# Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=100 "Unsupported configuration." for iPhone 11 on Xcode 11.4.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, face-id, truedepth-camera

I am trying to build a small app that uses the FaceID camera on an iPhone. The project was built for iPhone X but I am trying to run this on an iPhone 11 emulator (or my actual iPhone 11). I can't deploy it to my 11 because it immediately says "build failed" but when I try to run the iPhone 11 emulator, I see an error involving this:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=100 "Unsupported configuration." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported configuration., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The provided configuration is not supported on this device.}
```

I don't see iPhone X as an emulator type on Xcode (odd!). The iPhone 11 obviously has FaceID and TrueDepth so I'm not sure why this error would be happening. Any ideas? I'm very new to iPhone development so this is above my skill set at the moment.

Comment: The error says that ARKit isn't supported in the simulator, because it isn't. You need to provide more information on the "build failed" for the real device before we can help you